# When using Requirejs, is it possible to have the optimizer automatically find all the dependencies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have many modules. One module loads another module, which loads another module. Etc...

And of course, when I load the page, all of these modules load.  It works perfectly. Without the optimizer. (even though it takes a minute, because the browser has to load 50 things).

When I use optimizer...in my app.build.js, it seems that I have to manually specify each module!??

Why can't optimizer automatically traverse through the modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to specify the module you wanna optimize, not its dependencies. From the docs:

> In the modules array, specify the module names that you want to
>   optimize, in the example, "main". "main" will be mapped to
>   appdirectory/scripts/main.js in your project. The build system will
>   then trace the dependencies for main.js and inject them into the
>   appdirectory-build/scripts/main.js file.

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "scripts",
    dir: "../../appdirectory-build",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: When I do this, the optimizer will create "main.js" with everything minimized, and put only main's dependencies in there. It won't traverse to app.js, and then router.js, and then other modules....

Comment: I want optimizer to traverse through the modules, and then include THEIR dependencies in the main.js, like a multi-level tree. Main.js should have EVERY module inside.

Comment: Also, I put these options in my app.build.js:  optimizeAllPluginResources: true,
    findNestedDependencies: true,
 But they don't seem to have any effect

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

I had my paths wrong (I didn't understand baseURL , etc) . That's why things broke in the middle.